# How long will a javascript include get cached?

Tags: javascript, caching

I'm including an external javascript file in my page using

```
<script src="http://example.com/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How long will this script get cached by browsers? 
There is a

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Cache" content="no-cache" />
```

in my HTML. Will that make any difference?

Comment: IE doesn't care about a "Content-Cache" META tag, and I presume no other browser would either, as that's not a standards-based directive. See http://www.fiddler2.com/r/?httpperf for a primer on how browser caches work.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the browser.  The meta tag will have no effect on the scripts, just the page itself.  You'd have to modify your server settings to send a no-cache header for JavaScript:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching

Also, the best way to prevent browsers from caching your JavaScript when you push out a new release is to version the scripts.  Not sure if you're using some sort of automated build, but if so it is pretty easy to set up versioned JavaScript / CSS.

Comment: Specifically Expires, Cache-Control, Pragma, Last-Modified and ETag may influence caching.

Comment: thx. I'm getting: Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT. Does that mean it won't get cached outside the current session?

Comment: That SHOULD ensure that it doesn't ever get cached...however, I am not sure if all browsers will respect the headers properly.  As we all know some browsers (IE) do some very odd things.  That is why I recommended using version numbers on your JavaScript.  Since you are changing the name of the file each time you change the contents of the file, there is no way any browser would return an out dated version.

Answer (score 2):

> How long will this script get cached by browsers?

It depends on what the server is setting. Use a tool like Fiddler or Charles to see the headers.

Comment: Specifically, in Fiddler, see the CACHING response inspector.